# Length of missing array using javascript

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm trying to solve Length of missing array on CodeWars.
This is my code.

```js
function getLengthOfMissingArray(arr) {
  let result = 0;

  if (arr === null || arr.length === 0) return 0;

  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
  console.log(arr)

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    if (arr[i].length === 0 || arr[i] === null) return 0;

    else if (arr[i].length - arr[i + 1].length !== 1) {
      console.log(arr[i].length);
      console.log(arr[i + 1].length);

      result = arr[i].length - 1;
    }
  }
  return result;
}


console.log(getLengthOfMissingArray([
  [5, 2, 9],
  [4, 5, 1, 1],
  [1],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The problem is that I keep getting the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. The `console.log(arr[i + 1].length)` worked and showing `arr[i + 1].length` is 1. I'm really confused with this. Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at getLengthOfMissingArray (/home/chrx/Documents/codeWars/Length of missing array.js:8:45)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chrx/Documents/codeWars/Length of missing array.js:19:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:526:15)
    at startMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/node.js:439:3)
```

Comment: Hint: what happens in the loop iteration when `i` is `arr.length - 1`?

Comment: Please give link to problem

Comment: @yiw qi what is your expected output in this case?

Comment: Consider `[1,2,3]`. The last index in the array is `2`. When `i = 2`, `i + 1` is `3`. `arr[3]` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is an index overflow on the array at next line when performing the last iteration of the loop:

> `else if (arr[i].length - arr[i + 1].length !== 1)`

Particularly when evaluating this code: `arr[i + 1].length`

However, I have made some extra fixes to your code, they are explained within the code:

```js
function getLengthOfMissingArray(arr)
{
    // Check for all safe conditions at the start.

    if (!Array.isArray(arr) || arr.length === 0)
        return 0;

    if (arr.some(innerArr => !Array.isArray(innerArr)))
        return 0;

    // Sort mutates the array, there is no need to save it
    // again on arr variable.

    arr.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);

    // Start looping: to "arr.length - 1" maximum.

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
    {
        // If find the missing length, return here, don't keep iterating.
        if (arr[i].length - arr[i + 1].length !== 1)
            return arr[i].length - 1;
    }
}

console.log("[Good Test] Missing length: ", getLengthOfMissingArray([
  [5, 2, 9],
  [4, 5, 1, 1],
  [1],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
]));

// Check samples with errors:

console.log("[Bad Test 1] Missing length: ", getLengthOfMissingArray(null));

console.log("[Bad Test 2] Missing length: ", getLengthOfMissingArray([]));

console.log("[Bad Test 3] Missing length: ", getLengthOfMissingArray([
  [5, 2, 9],
  "what?",
  [1],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
]));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it shows the error is because it overflows the array.
Adding a check for arr[i + 1] should work.

```
if (!arr[i].length || !arr[i]|| !arr[i + 1]) return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop upto the last element but you access next element (i+1) in the loop, which means it will overflow because there is no element after the last element, hence create an error of undefined.

If you intent to access next element (i+1) in the loop, you should only loop upto one element before the last element (arr.length - 1).

Here is the working code.

```
function getLengthOfMissingArray(arr) {
  let result = 0;

  if (arr === null || arr.length === 0) return 0;

  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
  console.log(arr)

  // here is my only addition: loop upto a element before last element.
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {

    if (arr[i].length === 0 || arr[i] === null) return 0;

    else if (arr[i].length - arr[i + 1].length !== 1) {
      console.log(arr[i].length);
      console.log(arr[i + 1].length);

      result = arr[i].length - 1;
    }
  }
  return result;
}


console.log(getLengthOfMissingArray([
  [5, 2, 9],
  [4, 5, 1, 1],
  [1],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
]));
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea of arr.length - 1. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

When it will be the last iteration. `i` will be equal to `arr.length - 1` and `arr[i+1]` will be `undefined`. You first check if `arr[i+1]` exists or not.

```js
function getLengthOfMissingArray(arr) {
  let result = 0;
  if (arr === null || arr.length === 0) return 0;
  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length === 0 || arr[i] === null) return 0;
    else if (arr[i+1] && arr[i].length - arr[i + 1].length !== 1) {
      result = arr[i].length - 1;
    }
  }
  return result;
}


console.log(getLengthOfMissingArray([
  [5, 2, 9],
  [4, 5, 1, 1],
  [1],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @yiwqi The code still give error. You need add this line `arr =  arr.filter(a => a !== null)` before the `sort()` method to make the code pass all tests

Comment: In a test there is `null` inside array.so you need to remove it from otherwise it will give error when you will try to access `.length` of element in `sort()` method.